# Get data with button press from a JTable with Java

Tags: java, sql, button, netbeans, jtable

My term project in Computer Science I need to get a selected row and grab the information stored within a table from the first column from the selected row (after I press a button). After getting the information I need to store it into a previously initialized variable. I can't figure it out and any help is greatly appreciated.

This is what I have for selecting the row and trying to get the information from the row. I am using a button to run this so that it will remove a line from a database based on the information gathered from the stored string in the table.

```
    if (theMainViewDisplay.bookingData.getSelectedRow() != -1) {
            String bookingID;
            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)theMainViewDisplay.bookingData.getModel();
            model.removeRow(theMainViewDisplay.bookingData.getSelectedRow());

            // Get stored varible
            bookingID = model.getColumnName(1);
            System.out.println(bookingID);
    }
```

I tried getting the index of the model that was selected.

Comment: And where's your code? Wheres the table? What have you tried to find out how to access table data?

Comment: So I have added the code I have used. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can write a mouse listener for the table

To get values you can use `table.getModel().getValueAt(ROW_NUMBER,COLUMN_NUMBER)` function. In this code  raw is selected by mouse click event. hence the `table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint())` function returns the raw index clicked by mouse.

sample code look like this;

```
table.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {

     String symbol=(String)table.getModel().getValueAt(table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint()),0);

                    }

            } 
    }
```

You can read more about [JTABLES](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)  and 
[Java Mouse click Events](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

Comment: So I tried this but it still isn't grabbing the information from the table. Would there be another way I could go about doing this?

Comment: what you tried? so in this code when user double click the row it grab the string in the relevent `ROW_index` and COLUMN_INDEX=0 ,

Comment: dont just copy paste, here table is initialized by `defaultTableModel` and `ListSelectionModel` is set to `ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION`

Comment: So the one problem with it is I am trying to call it from a button. So when I press the button it removes it from a data base using the information from the table. I feel like I should have explained that better to start with.

Comment: you didnt mention anything about a button in the question, then write an event click for your button when a raw is selected

Comment: So I tried doing bookingID = (String)theMainViewDisplay.bookingData.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0); where row is equal to theMainViewDisplay.bookingData.getSelectedRow(); but I keep getting an error saying Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Comment: you cant get row that way, you need to implement a mouse event to get selected row

Comment: Also I noticed that the } total does not match the { bracket total and its messing with my code. Any thoughts? @namila007

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do it without a mouse listener. You can do it in the following way.

```
    private class RemoveBookings implements ActionListener {

         String bookingID;

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
             if (theMainViewDisplay.bookingData.getSelectedRow() != -1) {
                 final DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) theMainViewDisplay.bookingData.getModel();

                 // Get stored varible
                 int index = theMainViewDisplay.bookingData.getSelectedRow();
                 System.out.println(index);
                 theMainViewDisplay.bookingID = model.getValueAt(index, 0).toString();
                 theMainViewDisplay.pickUpLocation = model.getValueAt(index, 2).toString();
                 theMainViewDisplay.dropOffLocation = model.getValueAt(index, 3).toString();
                 System.out.println(theMainViewDisplay.bookingID);

                 // Remove booking from database
                 model.removeRow(theMainViewDisplay.bookingData.getSelectedRow());
                 theBackendModel.thePowList.remove(bookingID);
             }
         }
     }
```